# Set plot default outside of plot command for use in many plots

Tags: plotting

How can I set the default of the plot command in another part of the notebook?

if I have the following plots:

```
Plot[x , {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"], Style["y=x)", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]

Plot[x^2 , {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"], Style["y=x^2", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic]
```

how can I make it appear:

```
settings = ......;
   Plot[x , {x, 0, 15}, settings];
   Plot[x^2 , {x, 0, 15}, settings];
```

In a way that I could change the name of the label?

Comment: by defining `settings[lbl_]:=...`?

Comment: `settings = Sequence[PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"], Style["y=x)", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]`?

Comment: @Kuba &@ HenrikSchumacher: both does not work when I try to plot: ""Options expected (instead of plotset) beyond position 2 in Plot[.....]
An option must be a rule or a list of rules"

Comment: jarhead, you need to use it as `Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}, Evaluate@settings]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
settings = {PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
     Style[#, Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic} &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}, Evaluate[settings["y = x "]]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 15}, Evaluate[settings["y = " <> ToString[x^2, TraditionalForm]]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also temporarily set the options for `Plot`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plot}, 
 SetOptions[Plot, settings["y = x"]];
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 15}]]
```

> first picture above

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plot}, 
 SetOptions[Plot, settings["y = " <> ToString[x^2, TraditionalForm]]];
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 15}]]
```

> second picture above

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept this answer, however, Can it be written more elagantly? without the evaluate@?

Comment: @jarhead, my pleasure. You mean `Evaluate[settings["y = " <> ToString[x^2, TraditionalForm]]]` instead of `Evaluate@settings[...]`?

Comment: I mean in general, having just setting[arg1,arg2]

Comment: @jarhead - The `Evaluate` is needed because`Plot`has the attribute `HoldAll`. You can define a new function, say `myPlot`, that automates all of this for you.